# Using a MAC, print a Word document using a macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macos, printing, ms-word

I am using a MAC and I'm trying to create a macro that will print a Word document from my Excel worksheet. The user does not need to see the word document, they just need to print it.

After looking through some of the previous questions answered in this forum I managed to write some code that worked on my PC at home.

However, I changed the file path and filename and copied the code to my MAC that I am using at work and the code no longer seems to work. I wonder if the code has to be different when using a MAC?

I am using Microsoft Excel for Mac 2011, version 14.6.8.

```
ans = MsgBox(Prompt:="Document 1", Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Print")
If ans = vbYes Then
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    'Enter filename and path here
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("/Volumes/.../Document 1.docx")
    objWord.Visible = False
    objDoc.PrintOut
    objWord.Quit
End If
```

Sometimes the code gets stuck at `CreateObject("Word.Application")` and sometimes the code get stuck where I have written the file path and filename.

I'm not entirely sure that I have written the file path correctly..?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your file on a network?

Use that code in Word VBE to get the path of your file in the immediate window :

```
Sub get_path()
   Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Path
End Sub
```

Try this function to test if the file exists (not sure how to make this work on Mac...) :

```
Public Function File_Exist(sFilePath As String) As Boolean
    Dim sProv As String
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
        sProv = Dir(sFilePath, vbDirectory)

        File_Exist = (sProv <> "")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox Prompt:="Error on test file= " & sFilePath & vbCrLf & Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description
End Function
```

And your code with some improvements :

```
ans = MsgBox(Prompt:="Document 1", Buttons:=vbYesNo, Title:="Print")
If ans = vbYes Then
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    Dim sFilePath As String
    ''If the file is a network, you should start the path with //
    sFilePath = "New_path_from_Word_immediate_window"

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0


    objWord.Visible = False
    'Enter filename and path here
    'If File_Exist(sFilePath) Then
        Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(sFilePath)
        objDoc.PrintOut
        objDoc.Close
    'Else
        'MsgBox "File doesn't exist!" & vbCrLf & sFilePath, vbCritical + vbOKOnly
    'End If

    objWord.Quit
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Yes, my file is on a network.

Sorry I'm new to VBA so I have tried out both of your pieces of code but I can't seem to get either one to work.

I have added the "//" to the beginning of my file path. The total length of my file path is 160 characters long - I don't know if that is what is causing the problem?

The error message I am getting when I run the second piece of code that you sent says "Compile Error: User-defined type not define" and this highlights the code 
    objWord As Word.Application

Any ideas?

Comment: For the first piece of code which tests if the file exists or the file path is correct I get the error message "Compile error: Expected: expression"

Comment: @Hlrhodes : The length won't be an issue under 255 chars, try the edit (google immediate window if you don't know it). I've removed the `Word.App-Doc` and the test to see if the file exists, this should work that way. Not sure how to test the file existence on Mac... :/